# Error in OpenCV color conversion from BGR to grayscale

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to convert an image from BGR to grayscale format using this code:

```
img = cv2.imread('path//to//image//file')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

This seems to be working fine: I checked the data type of the `img` variable which turns out to be numpy ndarray and shape to be `(100,80,3)`. However if I give an image of a native numpy ndarray data type with same dimensions of the input of the `cvtColor` function, it gives me the following error:

```
Error: Assertion failed (depth == 0 || depth == 2 || depth == 5) in cv::cvtColor, file D:\Build\OpenCV\opencv-3.4.1\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp, line 11109
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.1) D:\Build\OpenCV\opencv-3.4.1\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:11109: error: (-215) depth == 0 || depth == 2 || depth == 5 in function cv::cvtColor
```

The code for the second case is (making a custom `np.ndarray` over here):

```
img = np.full((100,80,3), 12)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

Can anyone clarify what is the reason for this error and how to rectify it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is because your numpy array is not made up of the right data type. By default makes an array of type `np.int64` (64 bit), however, `cv2.cvtColor()` requires 8 bit (`np.uint8`) or 16 bit (`np.uint16`). To correct this change your `np.full()` function to include the data type:

`img = np.full((100,80,3), 12, np.uint8)`

Answer (score 7):

It may be easier to initialize new numpy array with initial image as source and `dtype=np.uint8`:

```
import numpy as np    
img = cv2.imread('path//to//image//file')    
img = np.array(img, dtype=np.uint8)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

Comment: I try to transform a 1-channel .tif to RGB with `cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB` , but I get this error:    `frame = np.array(frame, dtype=np.uint8)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'`  why?

Answer (score 4):

The error occured because the datatype of numpy array returned by `cv2.imread` is `uint8`, which is different from the datatype of numpy array returned by `np.full()`. To make the data-type as uint8, add the `dtype` parameter-

```
img = np.full((100,80,3), 12, dtype = np.uint8)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

Answer (score -1):

imagine you have a function called preprocessing() that preprocess your images with cv2, 
if you try to apply it as:

```
data = np.array(list(map(preprocessing,data)))
```

it won't work and that because np.array creates int64and you are trying to assign np.uint8 to it, what you should do instead is adding dtype parameter as follow:

```
data = np.array(list(map(preprocessing,data)), dtype = np.uint8)
```