# OpenCV cvtColor issue in python

Tags: python, opencv

[image]I am trying to follow the tutorial [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html) and I keep getting the following error. I read [in this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50319617/opencv-error-cv2-cvtcolor) that the issue is because `cvtColor` only takes 8 or 16 bit images.

My image is a png, from `plt.savefig()` in matplotlib and I think it is a 24-bit image.

1) Is my diagnosis of the problem correct or am I completely wrong?

2) Assuming 1) is true, I have been looking for ways to turn the 24-bit image into a 8/16 bit, but I haven't found anything so far. My matplotlib plot was a picture saved from a numpy array that is saved as `array.npy` file. Should I try to modify the `array.npy` file instead?

Tutorial code for reference:

```
import cv2 as cv

im = cv.imread("binary_graph_8.png")
imgray = cv.cvtColor(im, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv.threshold(imgray, 127, 255, 0)
im2, contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(thresh, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Error Message:

```
  File "C:/Users/ek247/.PyCharm2018.3/config/scratches/scratch_1.py", line 5, in <module>
    imgray = cv.cvtColor(im, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.0.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:181: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'
```

Comment: You say your image is a PNG but your code opens a JPEG? In general, people mean the same thing when they say an 8-bit and a 24-bit image because 8-bits per sample for Red, Green and Blue samples makes 24-bit per pixel.

Comment: My image is a PNG, but I posted the code straight from the tutorial which uses JPEG.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I went ahead and uploaded the picture and copied my code instead of the code from the tutorial, which in hindsight, seems to be the more sensible thing to do!

Comment: The assertion that your image isn't empty failed. So the only possible explanation is that your image is empty, i.e. it didn't load, so the path is probably incorrect.

Comment: You're right. I just tried to print out `im` and it came out None. I wonder why the image is coming up as empty, but at least I am not stuck anymore!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, check the answer of this entry, because it is what I was thinking in replying you:

[OpenCV !_src.empty() in function 'cvtColor' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52676020/opencv-src-empty-in-function-cvtcolor-error)

> This error happened because the image didn't load properly . So you
>   have problem with the previous line cv2.imread my suggestion is :
>
> ```
> - check if the images exist in the path you give
> - check the count variable if he have valid number
> ```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: It turns out my image was empty...I was actually just loading python in the wrong folder this whole time :( stupid mistake

Comment: Those happens sometimes. It was the first thing I imaged it, but they help to learn. :) Good luck!!